# adding custom <g> to nodes in a tree using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend

I am not a front-end developer. I am trying to build a tree in D3, where nodes might have a custom icon comming from the data as a  element:

Data example: (I have freedom of changing the structure if needed)

```
            {
                "name": "Top Level",
                "parent": "null",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "Level 2: A",
                        "parent": "Top Level",
                        "ico": "<g> <path d=\"M28...> <path d="" >...</path><\/g>"
                        "children": [
```

and my code looks like: (following http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html)

```
            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

            // Declare the nodes
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function (d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

            // Enter the nodes.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", "#fff");
```

How could I replace the `nodeEnter.append("circle")` by something like the following?

```
            /// create the icon of the node from the data
            nodeEnter.append("g")
                .attr("something", function(d) {
                    if( d.ico != null) {
                        return d.ico
                    }
                    else{
                        return circle().style("fill", "#fff"); 
                    }
                })
```

I can also force that every node brings an "ico" property and bring the circle in there

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it is a whole  component, inside I could expect any time of shapes.
The only way I found to do this was to edit the innerHtml property and attach the entire

Answer (score 1):

you can use [selection.each(function)](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.0/README.md#selection_each). Just change the `ico` member to have the path attribute of the path instead of the whole `<g>`. If you have multiple paths:

```
///  "ico": ["M28", "M34....",...]


/// create the icon of the node from the data
nodeEnter.each(fucntion(d) {

    const sel = d3.select(this);

    if( d.ico != null) {
        sel.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(d.ico)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", d);
    } else {
        sel.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! my "ico" is a "g" with multiple paths. How can I handle that? Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer for multiple paths.